# What is the right way to initialize a widget?

Tags: python, kivy

I've got a custom widget for showing errors in my Kivy app:

```
class ErrorWidget(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ErrorWidget, self).__init__(self, **kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(255/255.0, 99/255.0, 71/255.0)
            Rectangle(pos=((Window.size[0] / 2)-150,(Window.size[1] / 2)+200),
            size=(300,50))

...
...
class MainApp(App)

    def on_start(self):
        self.error_popup = ErrorWidget()
...
...
```

When I run this I get:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):


File "main.py", line 228, in <module>
     MainApp().run()
   File "/home/mark/front_end_android/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 949, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "/home/mark/front_end_android/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 944, in _run_prepare
     self.dispatch('on_start')
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "main.py", line 93, in on_start
     self.error_popup = ErrorWidget()
   File "main.py", line 50, in __init__
     super(ErrorWidget, self).__init__(self)
 TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

How am I giving it 2 arguments ? I can see in the `on_start` method I'm not passing any optional arguments. The `**kwargs` is there just in case I change my mind in the future.

**Update:**

I created minimal example but this is **working**:

```
class ErrorWidget(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ErrorWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(255/255.0, 99/255.0, 71/255.0)
            Rectangle(pos=((Window.size[0] / 2)-150,(Window.size[1] / 2)+200),
            size=(300,50))


class MainApp(app):

    def build(self):
        return ErrorWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this has any relevance to this but my Python distribution was bumped up from 3.8.2 to 3.8.5 and now I'm getting this error. I don't think I was getting the error when I had 3.8.2.

Comment: Are you running on Ubuntu 20?

Comment: Yes, 20.04. How do you know ?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and was unable to get the `python3-kivy` package to work with the python that gets installed with Ubuntu 20.04. I had to install Python 3.7.9 and install kivy under that python.

Comment: I'm using the latest RC version installed running `pip3 install --pre kivy`. I'm gonna try 3.7 then.

Comment: @JohnAnderson  I know Kivy has a known issue (https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6806) with getting wheels working in Python 3.8 . Devs are advised to use either 3.6, 3.7 or the latest RC version.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, I think I got it working by installing the `xsel` and `xclip`  packages. You might try that. The `TextInput` has a dependency on that.

Comment: Yep, works just fine under Python 3.7.9

Comment: @JohnAnderson  Feel free to post it as an answer so we can close this topic and you gonna get some points from SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
super(ErrorWidget, self).__init__(self)
 TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

This error means that `__init__` wasn't expecting the positional argument `self` that you passed. The reason for this is that the argument is just wrong, you don't need or want to pass self in this call.

Comment: Python disagrees with you:  `TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)`  :)

Comment: @Mark - Except python doesn't disagree. You don't include `self` on instance methods. So something is messed up in `Widget`.

Comment: If you do `print(type(super(ErrorWidget, self).__init__))` as the first line in your init, does it print `<class 'method-wrapper'>`? If so, `self` is not needed.

Comment: @Mark Python doesn't disagree at all, it's just informing you of a new error that was previously masked by this one. This one means that you're passing a kwarg that isn't handled by anything, leading to the given error message once the error propagates up the inheritance tree to `object`.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
super(ErrorWidget, self).__init__(self, **kwargs)
```

to:

```
super(ErrorWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

You should not include the `self` argument when calling `super`, it is supplied for you. If you include `self`, then it appears as an extra argument.

Comment: I took it off and left `**kwargs` only. I got this in terminal: `TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)`